# move away all zsh conf files from the home folder

Tags: command-line, home-directory, zsh

I could move all my zsh related files (.zshrc, .zprofile ...) to `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/zsh` setting the variable `ZOTDIR="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/zsh"` but there is a file I can't move: `.zprofile`.
This file is where I set the previous variable. I tried to set this on `/etc/zsh/zprofile` but a prompt to configure zsh is launched (when It doesn't detect a zshrc file). when I press `q` everything starts as expected. Is there a way to avoid the prompt or source from another file preventing this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

my fault, I was mistyping `etc/zsh/.zprofile`, for some reason I thought it didn't need the point before